# React - How to retrieve context using useContext - Cannot destructure property 'maps' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openlayers

I am trying to understand the context APIs for react and I have implemented openlayer Map using context

I want to get the map context at the time of mounting/loading the page. Is there a need to use state in it?

**mainapp.tsx**

```
 import MapContext from 'openlayer/Map/MapContext';
import maps from 'openlayer/Map';
<Provider store={store}>
        <HelmetProvider>
            <React.StrictMode>
                <StylesProvider injectFirst>
                  <MapContext.Provider value={{maps}}>
                            <App />
                   </MapContext.Provider>
                </StylesProvider>
            </React.StrictMode>
        </HelmetProvider>
    </Provider>
```

Where am I going wrong? Is there any alternate way?

Comment: Please, try to post the minimum amount possible of code, there is lots of useless/irrelevant code in this example. You don't need to use state, the context is enough. Check https://github.com/mmomtchev/rlayers for a working example that does exactly that (I am the author of the project).

Comment: @mmomtchev i have edited the question, I just want to select the map element in a different component. this is just to initialize the map so that  i can talk to map through a different html element

Comment: Your code looks ok, what value do you get for `MapContext` in your component?